# function not being called in the then section of Promise all

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

Inside my `componentdidmount` function of a react native component is this code

```
await Promise.all([
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[1],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[2],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[3],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[4],false)
    ]).then(() => {this.createConfluenceSummaryTable()})
```

If the last line of code reads like this

```
]).then(console.log("ALL DONE"))
```

Then i see then message in the console after everything is done, which is correct behaviour. So i know the promise all section works.
What doesnt work though is when i try and call the `createConfluenceSummaryTable` function. This function is part of the same component so I would usually call it using the `this.` Inside that function is another console.log statement saying `im running` but it never displays which leads me to believe that it is never called.

Why is the function not called? How do I call it properly?

Ive tried

`]).then(result => {createConfluenceSummaryTable})`

`]).then(result => {this.createConfluenceSummaryTable()})`

`]).then(this.createConfluenceSummaryTable())`

`]).then(createConfluenceSummaryTable())`

but nothing seems to trigger it

Comment: FYI, this `]).then(console.log("ALL DONE"))` is NOT correct.  It should be `]).then(() => console.log("ALL DONE"))`.  You have to pass a function reference to `.then()`.  Your code was executing the `console.log()` immediately and then passing nothing to `.then()`.  That's probably why you were seeing it execute.  It would suggest that you add a `.catch()` to see if there's an error happening.

Comment: It you want to use `then`, you should not use `async/await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't need the `.then` call since you are using async/await:

```
try {
    await Promise.all([
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[1],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[2],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[3],false),
        this.fetchDataFromExchange(timeframes[4],false)
    ]);
    this.createConfluenceSummaryTable()
} catch (e) {
    // something failed, check `e`
}
```

Your `.then(console.log())` is also not correct - you need to pass a function in `.then` and not call it directly there: `() => console.log(...)`.

Most likely one of your promises has an error which you can catch with a try/catch.